# Chuck Yeager Hat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Why does General Yeager's helmet have a red star on it?

[image]

The last time I saw a helmet like this, it belonged to the People's Liberation Army Air Force.

Answer (score 1):

[It isn't a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211869)... for whatever reason, this was the intended graphic. [Quoting Jaydles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211869/is-so-saying-that-chuck-yeager-was-a-secret-soviet#comment681549_211869):

> Deep down, I think we all knew that eventually, the decision to go with a color-blind designer would come back to bite us

Obviously a tongue-in-cheek answer, but this is perhaps the best we'll get ;-)